# Cordova social sharing callback always return true

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am implementing social sharing in ionic app.I am trying with http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/ plugin.It is working fine on  share but if I cancel, it always returns value `true`. My code is as following

```
$cordovaSocialSharing.share("title", "Share Video",current.file_path) 
      .then(function (result) { //always returning true value as result  })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of working option available for it like :-

1. https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-social-media-sharing-ionicframework/
2. http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Social-Sharing-in-Ionic-application.html
3. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/
4. http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-social-sharing-for-your-ionic-app/

Try that options.It may help you.

Comment: Hi Anuj Gupta thanks for the above links. social share is working for me but  when i am cancelling the share the callback response it gives as true. Actually in that point i need another msg like(false or share is cancelled). I am using native share sheet for user to pic an option.

Comment: ok fine.Why u didn't use err function here  . Try full code $cordovaSocialSharing.share("title", "Share Video",current.file_path) .then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });

Comment: I also used error function but its not triggering anything in error function

Comment: ok fine try with    $cordovaSocialSharing.share("title", "Share Video",current.file_path) .success(function (result) { console.log(result)}).error(function(data) { console.log(data)});

Comment: If you are facing issue then let me know .

Comment: In my case it is always returning false in android ionic.

Does any know how to solve that ?

Promise is working fine in iOS.

Comment: can you share what you did till now and where r u testing it .